# Installing scapy library in python windows

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

I have tried to install scapy for python on windows using the guide, but it didn't work.

How do I install it for use in a python script (version 2.7.5) in windows 7?  I have downloaded scapy-latest.zip

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this guide should work just fine, commend back if you have any errors!

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows

Comment: "...Just download the files and run the setup program" the setup program mentioned is setup.py? right click and run in idle ? or open cmd and run it with some parameters?

Comment: You need to install the module, this will show you how. https://docs.python.org/2/install/ You need to go into command prompt and type in "python setup.py install". If you get the error python is not a recognised command you need to put python in your environmental variables, just google that if you don't know how to.

Comment: i did all steps correctly as written. i  import it like so : "from scapy.all import *" as mentioned but when i try to do any function with scapy i get this error OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor...